Reboot and select proper boot device SSD error
My SSD worked fine for months, and is plugged in to the motherboard through separate power and data cables.
Recently I plugged out the data cable with the power cable still plugged in and booted the BIOS. After replacing the data cable, for any subsequent boot attempts I get the error in the title: "Reboot and select proper boot device".
The disk loads fine as a subsidiary device and is even recognized by the BIOS in boot settings; it just refuses to boot. Layout below when plugged in via a USB adapter into another Linux PC:

It appears the 512M EFI partition is fragile and was corrupted by pulling out the data cable. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

I followed the Debian instructions for reinstalling grub-efi, which can be summarized as follows:

Boot a live usb (or rescue mode on an install USB) on the BIOS and board you wish for your SSD to work on with kernel boot setting 'efi=runtime'
Execute a shell in your root partition, and make sure all other partitions are correctly mounted in relation to your root partition. chroot into root filesystem
grub install /dev/sdX, where X is the disk whose EFI partition you wish to fix.
update-grub
exit chroot (Ctrl+D), shutdown, remove the Live USB, and reboot

I am glad I could fix this, but I still am unclear how this partition could be so easily corruptible by removing the Data cable.

When a drive is removed, most UEFI systems remove or change the UEFI entry. You have to then restore that entry with chroot or Boot-Repair or efibootmgr. See man efibootmgr and this shows UEFI entries, compare working system with what it shows after you remove a drive. sudo efibootmgr -v. several examples: https://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win
